# MySQL LIMIT before Grouping?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to LIMIT Grouped results to 30, but instead I'm grouping all rows and then limiting it to 30 groups. How do I do the opposite?

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM `Posts` GROUP By `Category` LIMIT 30
```

Comment: What exactly do you want? Maximum of 30 rows per category?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM (SELECT * FROM `Posts` LIMIT 30) t GROUP By `Category`
```

Comment: Please do not give code-only answers. Describe how you used a subquery to achieve the desired result.